# How can We set Height to flexislider?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I cannot set a height to flexislider.I guess this issue about flexislider.js.And Also about responsive design.

FlexiSlider html like this:

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YSVlz2Z.jpg" />
      <h2><a href"#">First Link Here</a></h2>
      <p>Some text here that could be a message</p>
      <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Another Link Here</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YSVlz2Z.jpg" />
      <h2><a href"#">Second Link Here</a></h2>
      <p>Some text here that could be a message</p>      
    </li>
    <li>
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YSVlz2Z.jpg" />
     <h2><a href"#">Third Link Here</a></h2>
     <p>Some text here that could be a message</p>     
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can we solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Please post JSFiddle link where you show how you try to set the height

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can assign a hight to the .flexslider, the issue is rather about the content that you have inside .flexslider. To check whether your assigned hieght is applied or not, just simply (temporary) add a style with outline to your div like:

```
<div class="flexslider" style="outline: 1px solid red; height: 50px">
</div>
```

this will allow you visually clarify the hieght of a div.
But I guess for the current issue, it seems to use overflow property for the div, simply use

```
<div class="flexslider" style="outline: 1px solid red; height: 50px; overflow: hidden">
```

you may learn more about overflow at [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Comment: Thanks .This seem may help.But The elements cant resize in div of flexislider.You can check this at http://www.gustavofadel.com/ .

Comment: if you want the height to be responsive - I mean flexible to the screen or div, then you have to write instead of for example  height: 100px; width: 320px, 

max-width: 320; there is no need to specify height since when the width changes the height will be altered automatically